# Is there anywhere to setup ssl certificate on Apache Windows ? I found error SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin is not supported on Win32

Tags: apache, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, appserver

I am trying to install SSL on Apache Windows with a certificate purchased and downloaded from Godaddy. There are 3 files, 2 files as .crt and 1 file as .pem.

I have completed every step, all I have left is to put the location of cert and error. I failed to install and got the error below.

Is there a way I can install this certificate please tell me step by step as I have never installed it before.

> AH02577: Init: SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin is not supported on Win32
> (key file C:/AppServ/Apache24/conf/website-example.pem) AH02311: Fatal
> error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See
> C:/AppServ/Apache24/logs/error.log for more information AH02564:
> Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key website-example:443:0,
> check C:/AppServ/Apache24/conf/website-example.pem SSL Library Error:
> error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag SSL
> Library Error: error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding
> routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error SSL Library Error:
> error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag SSL
> Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding
> routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error (Type=RSAPrivateKey)
> SSL Library Error: error:04093004:rsa routines:old_rsa_priv_decode:RSA
> lib SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding
> routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag SSL Library Error:
> error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1
> error (Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO)

Thank you so much for you helping.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue. Step is go to server.pem (server.key) directories and run command below

```
openssl rsa -in server.key -out server_new.key
```

Next, Comment out `SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin` in http-ssl.conf file (put # in front of that line)

that's all